# How to set application fees in Stripe while authorize and change amount using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

In my application, I have to first authorise `(Block the payment)` the amount from both user. And once they both clicks on confirm once they received the service, I need to perform the charge `(Actual cut and transfer payment)`.

I can do this and works fine but hear I want to get the platform fees but when I add the param of `application_fee_amount` then it `throws` an `error` and says I can only perform this when I do a direct payment transfer.

I think this is very common case which may exist other apps also.

How I'm doing in code...

```
let obj = {
        amount: convertToCents(data.amount),
        currency: 'usd',
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        capture_method: 'manual',
        application_fee_amount: convertToCents(data.amount *0.05), // 5% as a plateform fees...
        payment_method: data.payment_method,
        customer: data.customer,           
        confirm: true
    }
    console.log(obj);
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(obj);
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are using a Connect fund flow, like Destination Charges or Direct. ApplicationFees can only be taken on Connect fund flows.

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges

Are you using Connect?

Comment: Thanks for your answer first. And yes I'm not using connct. Do you think it's essential to use it?

Comment: Stripe Connect is a requirement for application fees. You'll only be taking Application Fees on a payment you make to a Connect account, otherwise App Fees are irrelevant on a non-Connect setup.